# What would be the meaning of "adi"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, affixes

PMEG does not provide a theorical meaning for [adi](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/ad.html#i-l65). What would be the most probable meaning of *adi* based on how other affixes are transformed into verbs?

Answer (score 4):

The suffix *-ad-* points to actions, repeated actions, long activities, and habits. You will occasionally see *ada* and *ade* used to mean "continual(ly), habitual(ly)".

*Adi fari* is rare but means "keep on doing, continue doing" (in a fairly purposeful way):

> *...vi adis defraŭdi abundon da faruno...*  ...you appropriated over a long period a great quantity of flour... (From *La skandalo pro Jozefo*)

As for *adi* without a verb following it, I think I would interpret it as "continue actively" or "busy oneself". The word *umadi* already means "linger, potter around" but *adi* sounds a little more strenuous.

> *Li nin vizitadis.* He visited us a great deal.
>
> *Li ade vizitis.* He continually paid visits.
>
> *Li adis viziti.* He kept on visiting.
>
> *La laboro ados senfine.* The work will be unceasing.
>
> *Li adis en la riparejo.* He fussed around / spent a lot of time in the workshop.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say *adi* + *$VERBROOTi* = *$VERBROOTadi*

Do you have a sentence with *adi* as independend verb in mind?

Comment: Not really. I was looking to a shorter alternative to "daŭrigi" but was not sure if I could use "adi" for this.

Answer (score 0):

Eble kiel:

> Mi diris ke li ne bezonas kontroladi, sed li adas

sed tiu estas nur opinio.